# Selenium XPATH i am trying to select a radio button from column 2 of table where text is name

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a table of 5 columns.  Column 2 has some text for the Name.  Column 1 is a radio button.  Column 3, 4 and 5 is a radio button.
I would like to select the radio button from column 3 where name text is "MaidenName"

I can find MaidenName then i tried to use following-sibling to go to the next column.  My XPATH is not working.

My XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"]/tbody//tr//td//div//span[text()="MAIDENNAME"]/following-sibling::td[2]//div//span[@type="radio"]
```

The HTML sample is:

```
    <table id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body" cellspacing="0"
       style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    # few trs here. I have removed. too long to paste otherwise
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="12">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1076" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="DOB"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DOB</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1077" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rb3386"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1078" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rb3386"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1079" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" checked="" name="rb3386"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="13">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBHG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1075" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow119"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBBH">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG GJPPK2LBMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="14">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1076" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span title="MAIDENNAME"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">MAIDENNAME</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1077" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rb3388"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1078" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rb3388"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH GJPPK2LBNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1079" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" checked="" name="rb3388"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="15">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="16">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Having found MaideName I would like to go down 2 columns and select the radio button in the 2nd column from MaidenName

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stop at the `tr` point checking that there is `MAIDENNAME` text inside the appropriate column and then get the desired column in this row:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"]/tbody//
    tr[td[2]/div/span/text()="MAIDENNAME"]/
        td[3]/div/input[@type="radio"]
```

newlines added for readability.

Also note that I also had to fix the tag name - you are targeting the `input` element and not the `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out now.  I should use the following attribute.  It is in the same tr row.  following-sibling would go down to the next tr node.
Need to stay in the same node.

My working XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"]/tbody//tr//td//div//span[text()="MAIDENNAME"]/following::td[2]//div//input
```